# Minecraft Launcher will not launch, it gives Exception Access Violation error, Problematic Frame atioglxx.dll

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I just recently downloaded and updated Minecraft to 1.7.5 but the launcher says this

```
[17:26:00 INversions\1.7.5\1.7.5.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main    
[17:26:08 INFO]: Client> [17:26:08] [main/INFO]: Setting user: Shedi78    
[17:26:08 INFO]: Client> [17:26:08] [main/INFO]: (Session ID is token:d7dc7d08fc2d4c7d97eb30426166598e:46840aade317405fbfb0589b141bb8e6)    
[17:26:08 INFO]: Client> [17:26:08] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.1   
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #    
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:  
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #   
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x690ba2a1, pid=4676, tid=4132    
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #  
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)   
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )   
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # Problematic frame:  
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # C  [atioglxx.dll+0x8a2a1]  
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #  
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows  
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # 
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid4676.log
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. 
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
[17:26:09 INFO]: Client> #
[17:26:09 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
[17:26:09 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.5\1.7.5-natives-179381928934273
[17:26:09 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[17:26:09 WARN]: Couldn't delete C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.5\1.7.5-natives-179381928934273 - scheduling for deletion upon exit
```

Answer (score 3):

- Backup your saves
- Delete the `.minecraft` folder.
- Uninstall/reinstall Java.
- Reinstall Minecraft.

You may have incompatible mods. If you have messed around with the JVM, that may be causing the problem.

I'm not a java expert, so don't quote me on this, but judging from the error log, something is wrong with your JVM.

Answer (score 3):

I would uninstall & delete everything that has to do with your Minecraft/Java, (delete it from the recycling bin as well), and reinstall all of it.

Get the [latest Java version](http://java.com/en/), the latest Minecraft version, and make sure that any mods you download are compatible with your Minecraft version (even Forge, that could be the problem, make sure that is compatible too).

After all of that has been reinstalled, I would restart my computer and see what happens. I had this same problem and this helped me, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have mods that are not compatible with 1.7.5.  Try moving everything in the `%appdata%/.minecraft/mods` folder someplace else, and launch again.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons this is happening, out of date mods, you accidentally downloaded the wrong OS version, your java is corrupted, or the game's files are corrupted somehow.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using mods that are only compatible with Minecraft 1.7.4 just delete them - because they won't work unless they were updated.

You will need to wait for the update for these mods and re-install them when it comes out, because they won't work otherwise.